# How to get a list of discontinuous points from a piecewise function

Tags: piecewise

I want to find a list of discontinuous points from a piecewise function.

Suppose I have a function

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[
  {
    {x, -1 <= x < -0.1}
   ,{-2 x^2, -0.1 <= x < 1}
  }
 ]
```

I want to get list like `{-1,-0.1,1}`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new user of Mathematica.

Comment: this is your second questions, and both have been closed as the answer was something you could have found with a quick search. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy, but I strongly suggest for you to read the documentation available, both for Mathematica and for the Mma.SE site. Do learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).